Why are absorbing bodies hotter over time than reflecting bodies?
I recently learnt about energy transfer by EM Waves and came across the formula for momentum transfer, i.e.
Δp = U/c → perfect absorption
Δp = 2U/c → perfect reflection
then why do absorbing bodies become hotter over time? (A practical example is wearing white apparel in summers)

What does momentum transfer have to do with temperature? The point is that a better absorber converts more of the incident power to heat.

If a photon is absorbed, then the energy that it is carrying is fully absorbed by the material. If a photon is perfectly reflected, most of the energy of the photon is carried away, whereas only a tiny amount corresponding to the recoil of the mirror will be converted into kinetic energy of the mirror. There are many constraints involved; it is not so easy as to simply say that more momentum transfer implies more energy transfer.

Photon momentum has nothing to do with the temperature of an object sitting in the sun. All objects have a natural tendency to absorb the energy contained in sunlight and a natural tendency to re-emit that energy as they heat up. What drives the buildup of heat in a non-reflective body is that the photon frequencies at which the energy is being absorbed (instead of simply being reflected away) are not the same as the frequencies at which the object radiates- so the net absorption is a bit greater than the emissivity. In fact the absorptivity/emissivity ratio is a figure of merit for solar energy collectors.
